# Is there any theory on the order of Autoregression model for periodic time series?

Tags: time-series, references, autoregressive, embeddings

Say M periodic signals, then one can safely say using AR-M model can achieve the perfect prediction. But how about further, in a more general sense, is there any publications on this?

### Update:

Here is my arXiv paper on this problem
https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.05198

Answer (score 2):

If you have a perfectly predictable signal periodic in frequency $f$, the pattern repeats every cycle, or $1/f$ time units.

You need a single lag to predict it, the series lagged by $1/f$ time units. So AR-$1/f$ model will achieve perfect prediction, where the only lag included is the one mentioned.

Comment: yes, it is! I am now writing a paper, and I considered many cases, including the one you mentioned as a special case. But since I am not very knowledgable in the time series modeling field, I hope to see if anyone has done this. I google a lot and cannot find anything.

Comment: After half a year... Here is the arXiv! https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.05198